# How to unpack bundle file?

Tags: git, bundle

I received .bundle file in my mail(let we assume the file name is file.bundle). It comes with command instruction to unpack the bundle file like this:
git clone file.bundle

Do I miss any other step before I clone the bundle. I am new with Git, please help me..

I tried:

1. git init
2. git clone file.bundle

What to expect:
Unpack the bundle file into a docker scripts for running postgres database

What I got:
"fatal:repository file.bundle does not exist"

Comment: What does this have to do with Postgres? Please either explain how Postgres is relevant or remove the Postgres tag.

Comment: Just ruling out some obvious elements : if the file is indeed a git bundle, you should save it on disk, and run `git clone path/to/file.bundle` from a terminal. Is that what you did ? when you ran `git clone file.bundle`, did you run it from the directory where you saved `file.bundle` ?

Comment: In some versions of Git, `git clone` has a small bug when dealing with a bundle file as input, such that you must provide the *full path name* to the file. (There is at least one other workaround but the full path name is the simplest method.)

Answer (score 0):

Running `git init` will create a new git repo, you do not need that.

Just open your terminal and go to the location of you .bundle file and run `git clone file.bundle`